# iPhone. Problem after moving a view out of screen to inside the screen

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I think the title of the question is quite bad explained so I'll try to make it better here. I have an UIViewController project. Inside the main view I've put another smaller view (320x200), let's call it **menu**. This view it's mostly placed out of the visible screen, at point (0, -180) so when the app is launched, the top 20px displayed are from menu and the rest is the main view. Clear so far?

When the user touches that visible part of the menu (there's an UIButton) the whole **self.view** moves down with an animation so the whole menu us displayed. This menu has more buttons to go to other views and do other stuff, but when touching the buttons they don't response at all. How to make buttons work? Any tips here?

I've post some images, because it seems a bit messy :P

[image: before]
[image: after]

**Adding code as requested:**
When I say the view moves, yes I mean the frame, with an animation like this:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"MenuAnimationShow" context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[self.view setFrame:CGRectOffset([self.view frame], 0, menu.frame.size.height-15)];
self.view.center = CGPointMake(160, 240 + menu.frame.size.height - 15);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

And also, yes, the buttons are connected to IBAction but when you click nothing happens. I have some NSLog in each of them but never gets to log anything. It's like you never touch them. If I put the menu UIView over the main view (self.view) they are not working either. More than that, is like menu is ignored because if there's something below (zPosition), you can touch that item.

Comment: What do you mean by self.view moves?  Posting some relevant code will probably help.  Do you have a UIView for the menu?  Are you moving the frame of that view?

Comment: It may be banal: have you connected those buttons to some IBAction?

Comment: menu is an UIView inside the main view, so if I move the self.view frame I'm also moving the frame for menu, right? or I'm wrong here? Gonna give that a try

Comment: Maybe Touch events does not occur because your 'menu' is outside view controller's view. You should not move VC's view. You have to put 2 subviews and move them instead of moving view controller's view.

Comment: Thank's mate, you comment gave me the solution by using @RyanJM code too. Finally works fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be moving self.view you should be moving the frame of the menu, and you only need to move the center since that will effect the frame position (I'm assuming your width/height of the frame isn't supposed to change).

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"MenuAnimationShow" context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
self.menu = CGPointMake(320/2, menu.frame.size.height/2);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: Thanks! that worked I used this idea and also @beefon's. In the animation I changed the center of a new view below the menu and the menu. So after moving, it's finally interactive. Thak you guys!

Comment: You shouldn't need to put the menu in another view. Moving it directly should be just fine. Keep your views as simple as possible. But I'm glad you got it figured out.